# Why do only 2 of my 3 Highcharts Pie Charts/Graphs are showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I can't figure out why my charts show up just fine when I upload it to jfiddle, however, in my actual page only 2 of the 3 charts show up.

Am I missing something? All of my javascript code and tags are closed. Can't figure this one out at all.  You can see my code at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZcRX/

here is my entire HTML PAGE... I can not see why my charts will not show up but show up just fine in JSFiddle:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Graphs & Charts</title>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript Document
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
 colors: ['#6eb5ec', '#d64646', '#8bba00', '#f6bd0f', '#cd5ace', '#f19153', '#cccccc', '#cd8b49']
});

    var chart;  

        // Build the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                events: {
                    load: function(event) {
                        console.log(this);
            }
        }     
            },
                legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                floating: true,
                x: 365,
                y: 260,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    fontSize: '11px'
                    }
            },
             title: {
                text: '2012 Revenue Report'
            },
                tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    showInLegend: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            legendItemClick: function () {
                                return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                                }
                            }   
                        }   
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Govt<br/>Contracts<br/>& Grants',   45.0],
                    ['Private<br/>Grants/Gifts',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Net Tuition<br/>& Fees',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Auxiliary<br/>Enterprises',    8.5],
                    ['Investments',     6.2],
                    ['Dental Clinic',   0.7],
                    ['Other',   0.7]
                ]
            }]

        });
    });



       // ENDOWMENT BAR GRAPH
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'endowment',
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                        load: function(event) {
                            console.log(this);
            }
        }     
            },
            title: {
                text: '2012 Financial Endowment Report'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Periods ending June 30th'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Reporting Year'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Millions (mm)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 85,
                y: 50,
                floating: true,
                shadow: true
            },
            showInLegend: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            legendItemClick: function () {
                                return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                                }
                            }   
                        },  
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    showInLegend: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            legendItemClick: function () {
                                return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                                }
                            }   
                        }

                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'Yr 2011',
                data: [49.9]

            }, {
                name: 'Yr 2012',
                data: [83.6]

            }]

        });


       // EXPENSES CHART
              chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
             renderTo: 'expenses',
             plotBackgroundColor: null,
             plotBorderWidth: null,
             plotShadow: false
          },
          title: {
             text: 'This will be a pie chart',
             style: {
                Color: '#666'
             }
          },
          tooltip: {
             formatter: function() {
                return '<strong>'+ this.point.name +'</strong>: '+ this.y +' %';
             }
          },
          plotOptions: {
             pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                   enabled: true
                },
                showInLegend: true
             }
          },
          showInLegend: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            legendItemClick: function () {
                                return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                                }
                            }   
        },  
          series: [{
             type: 'pie',
             name: 'Our Current Expenses',
             data: [
                ['Expense1', 26.9],
                ['Expense2', 27.7],
                ['Expense3', 45.3],
                {
                   name: 'Other',
                   y: 32.2,
                   sliced: true,
                   selected: true
                }
             ]
          }],
          legend: {
             borderColor: '#666'
          }
       });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="expenses" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="endowment" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check for errors in the console section

Comment: If your markup isn't too massive, I'd suggest posting it here or a link to the real site. Difficult to diagnose a working piece of code.

Comment: No idea, as you can see it works, try to debug your code.

Comment: I just updated my post with my entire HTML page. Please have a look and give me your ideas as to why my chart shows up fine in JSFiddle and not when I upload it to my server!?

Answer (score 3):

I see a variety of issues. First, try including jQuery before all other scripts. The [Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) states that it depends on jQuery, MooTools or Prototype. This probably works in jsfiddle because it loads jQuery into the browser by default.

Second, you should put all of the chart creation inside the $(document).ready(function () {}) block. Only your revenue chart was being initialized in that block.

Take a look at a slightly revised, working stand-alone version at http://static.nickfishman.com/misc/12737085.html

Comment: @MizAkita, if this answer fixes your issue, please accept it (click the check mark next to it). [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for a full explanation of how accepting answers works on stackoverflow.

Comment: Confirming this to be the right answer. Had the same issue when I copied some existing working code and updated the jquery to a new version placing it below the highcharts.js.  Once jquery was put before highcharts.js it started working again just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

in your javascript. I can see that you're already initializing an event on document ready, so this is reduntant, may be causing the problem you're facing. Try without it.

This way here http://jsfiddle.net/kZcRX/1/

Comment: Hmmm.... how is it possible for it to work in JS Fiddle and not in my document. I simply copies and pasted the code from JSFiddle and it still doesnt work! HMMMMMM... stumped!

Comment: I just updated my post with my entire HTML page. Please have a look and give me your ideas as to why my chart shows up fine in JSFiddle and not when I upload it to my server!?